# Boundary of spring transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have two spring services. Service1.foo() which is not transactional calls Service2.bar() which is transactional. So I am wondering if my transaction will only be limited to service2.bar(). I want to make sure that Service1.foo() is not run in transaction. Is my code correct?

```
class Service1 
{
    public void foo() {
        //some non transaction code
        service2.bar();
        //some non transaction code
    }
}

@Transactional
class Service2 
{
    public void bar() {
        //TODO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. *If* you have setup transaction support correctly and you are using the right import (`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`) for @Transactional, then only the methods in Service2 run inside a transaction, and the methods in Service1 do not.

If the setup is not correct, nothing runs inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code will work for the scenario you mentioned.  See my code example below, after executing it, only 1 record got inserted into TEST_TABLE with CD=INSERT3. I put the wrong column in insert from Dao2impl, to fail the transaction.

Below is Service1 class, from where I am calling insertMainServiceCall method that has a call to insertData method which need to be executed in transaction:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

@Autowired
private Service2 service2;

@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public Service2 getService2() {
    return service2;
}

public void setService2(Service2 service2) {
    this.service2 = service2;
}


public DataSource getDatasource() {
    return datasource;
}

public void setDatasource(DataSource datasource) {
    this.datasource = datasource;
}

public void insertMainServiceCall(){
    String sqlCmd="INSERT INTO   TEST_TABLE " +
            "(CD, NAME, DEPT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);

    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlCmd, new Object[] {"INSERT3",
            "INSERT3","INSERT3"  
    });

    service2.insertData();
}
```

}

Below is my Service2 class :

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class Service2 {

@Autowired
private Dao1 dao1;

@Autowired
private Dao2 dao2;

public Dao1 getDao1() {
    return dao1;
}

public void setDao1(Dao1 dao1) {
    this.dao1 = dao1;
}

public Dao2 getDao2() {
    return dao2;
}

public void setDao2(Dao2 dao2) {
    this.dao2 = dao2;
}

public void insertData(){
    dao1.insert1();
    dao2.insert2();
}

}
```

Below is my Dao1Impl class code:

```
@Repository
public class Dao1Impl implements Dao1{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public void insert1(){
    String sqlCmd="INSERT INTO   TEST_TABLE " +
            "(CD, NAME, DEPT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlCmd, new Object[] {"INSERT1",
            "INSERT1","INSERT1"  
    });
}


public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

}

Below is my Dao2Impl class code:

```
@Repository
public class Dao2Impl implements Dao2 {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public void insert2(){
    String sqlCmd="INSERT INTO   TEST_TABLE " +
            "(CD, NAME, DEPT1) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlCmd, new Object[] {"INSERT2",
            "INSERT2","INSERT2"  
    });
}


public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


}
```

In spring-config.xml, you need to setup transactional support as below: -

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
```